# How to install chemfig through apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, latex

I'm doing some LaTeX and I need the chemfig package.
As usual, I type the package name in synaptic but this time nothing matches the search.

Does anyone know how to install it ?

Is it possible through apt-get because I want to list all the packages needed to install to compile my LaTeX source file for other people willing to compile it.

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

EDIT: It seems [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100929/how-to-install-latex-package-called-standalone-properly-so-i-can-get-update-wi) answers my question :)
I should have checked deeper if a related question hadn't already been posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install LaTeX package called "standalone" properly so I can get update with Synaptic package manager?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100929/how-to-install-latex-package-called-standalone-properly-so-i-can-get-update-wi)

Comment: Please either add your answer as such, or delete your question, as it appears unanswered in the list. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX-live included with Ubuntu is very old (2009 version). You should install the latest 2011 version from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

That includes a TeX package manager called `tlmgr`, which makes installing any package from the CTAN library *extremely* easy. You can then install the package with `tlmgr install chemfig`.

Note that `chemfig` uses TikZ as its backend, but `tlmgr` should also take care of such dependencies for you.

Comment: Has anyone managed to get this approach to work? I installed the 2012 version and tlmgr is not working

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness: In the current LTS (14.04) `chemfig` is found in the `texlive-pictures` package.